# Visual Studio 2019 при запуске setup загрузка идетпри запуске Visual Studio просто черный экран, все перепробовал

Tags: visual-studio

помогите прошу....[image: вот черный экран...] перепробывал поменять названия установщика, открыть от имени администратора, переустановить, поменять темы в персонализации, написать в свойствах добавить в названиях, непомню команды но что-то с гамой связанно.

Answer (score 0):

попробуй запустить установщик с консоли добавив параметр "-disable-gpu"

Или зайди в NVIDIA Control Panel и в блоке 'Manage 3D settings' поставь 'Visual Studio Installer' в исключения что бы открывало встроенной графикой

Иногда может помочь банальное обновление драйверов на все железо.

Еще можно правой кнопкой мыши и выбрать режим совместимости со старыми версиями виндовс попробовать. Так же может помочь.